# Unable to list blobs from Azure VM with Python using system assigned managed identity

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am try to list all blobs available in azure storage container. Below is the python code

```
import io
import os
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError, ResourceExistsError
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import MSIAuthentication
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, BlobLeaseClient, BlobPrefix, ContentSettings

class BlobSamples(object):
    # <Snippet_list_blobs_flat>
    def list_blobs_flat(self, blob_service_client: BlobServiceClient, container_name):
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)

        blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()

        for blob in blob_list:
            print(f"Name: {blob.name}")
    # </Snippet_list_blobs_flat>

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # TODO: Replace <storage-account-name> with your actual storage account name
    account_url = "https://testinglist.blob.core.windows.net"
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

    # Create the BlobServiceClient object
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=credential)

    sample = BlobSamples()
    sample.list_blobs_flat(blob_service_client, "testing")
```

I am running this code from virtual machine which has the below system assigned managed identity.

[image]

WHen i execute code getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listblob.py", line 28, in <module>
    sample.list_blobs_flat(blob_service_client, "testing")
  File "listblob.py", line 15, in list_blobs_flat
    for blob in blob_list:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/core/paging.py", line 128, in __next__
    return next(self._page_iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/core/paging.py", line 76, in __next__
    self._response = self._get_next(self.continuation_token)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_list_blobs_helper.py", line 83, in _get_next_cb
    process_storage_error(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/response_handlers.py", line 181, in process_storage_error
    exec("raise error from None")   # pylint: disable=exec-used # nosec
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:32c35c2b-101e-0066-801f-932ff0000000
Time:2023-05-30T17:55:50.1950002Z
ErrorCode:AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:32c35c2b-101e-0066-801f-932ff0000000
Time:2023-05-30T17:55:50.1950002Z</Message></Error>
```

The container is private but accessible from all networks. I am unable to catch the issue. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

It is my mistake i was creating defaultazurecredential while it requires below one.

```
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
```

This worked for me.